# Problem with project running on wrong localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a Web API project (MapBackend). I want to start the project at MapBackend-applicationUrl (https://localhost:5001) bu it starts ssl port (https://localhost:44365/). So this project is not working. How can I solve this problem ?

Proof that it doesn't work:
[Proof 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOovf.png)
[Proof 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3evoY.png)

This is my launchSettings.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:43928",
      "sslPort": 44365
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MapBackEnd": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Kestrel configuration from Visual Studio dropdown box:

[image]

In your case the name under the "IIS Express" will be "MapBackEnd"

Answer (score 0):

Check your appsettings.json file and see if you have something like this inside:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://*:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

On this port your application will run when started from the VisualStudio.

Comment: there is no this part in my appsettings.json file. I added but unfortunately it still didn't work